# Opencv webcam camera check variable status after a time period

Tags: python, opencv, webcam, gesture, detection

I writing a code to detect human fist inside a box from the webcam. What i want is after checking there is a fist inside, the program will wait for 2 seconds. After 2 seconds, if there is still a fist inside, then it will put a text "FIST"
Here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from detect import detect_fist

import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
isFist = 0

while (cap.isOpened()):

    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (50, 50), (150, 150), (0, 255, 0), 0)
    confirm = img[50:150, 50:150] # narrow the whole webcam to a box 

    isFist = detect_fist(confirm) # a function to detect fist inside that box

    if isFist:
        timeout = int(time.time()) + 2
        while 1:
            if int(time.time()) == int(timeout):
                cv2.putText(img, "Fist", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 2)

                break

    cv2.imshow('Gesture', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
```

my problem is after it detect my fist in the box ,the camera display turn slowly , almost freeze. What i want is the camera still working normally and will check the fist again after 2 secs.

I suggest this is due to the checking of condition `if int(time.time()) == int(timeout)` will be executed following the frame rate of the webcam ( which is really fast ) there for the display part cannot follow.

Anyone have any idea to archive this ?

Answer (score 0):

When a fist is detected, your code is stuck in the while loop, which is why you see the image window as being 'stuck'. I recommend using a bool to keep track of the status. I've modified your code to show the effect, although I have not debugged this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from detect import detect_fist

import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
isFist = 0
current_time = 0 
target_time = 0
first_fist_detection = False
while (cap.isOpened()):

    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.flip(img, 1)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (50, 50), (150, 150), (0, 255, 0), 0)
    confirm = img[50:150, 50:150] # narrow the whole webcam to a box 

    isFist = detect_fist(confirm) # a function to detect fist inside that box


    current_time = int(time.time())

    if isFist and not first_fist_detection:
        first_fist_detection = True
        target_time = current_time + 2
    elif isFist and first_fist_detection:
        if current_time > target_time:
            cv2.putText(img, "Fist", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, 2)
    else:
        #that is, no fist is detected
        first_fist_detection = False        

    cv2.imshow('Gesture', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == 27:
        break
```